# Lanchester's Square Law query

Tags: dynamical-systems

Lanchester's Square Law states that given two armies, $x$ and $y$, with the army units' relative effectiveness $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively, this can be written as two differential equations for the sizes of the armies as a function of time:
$$\dot{x}=-\beta y,$$
$$\dot{y}=-\alpha x.$$

My question is as follows: Are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ independent of time and constant throughout the battle such that: $$\alpha x^2-\beta y^2= c$$
If so, how can this be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants is an assumption, not a conclusion.

From $$\frac{dx}{dt} = - \beta y$$
and $$\frac{dy}{dt} = - \alpha x$$
we have, by the chain rule,
$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{\beta}{\alpha} \frac{y}{x}$$
so
$$\alpha x \; dx = \beta y \;dy$$
Integrating,
$$\frac{1}{2} \alpha x^2 = \frac{1}{2} \beta y^2 + C_1$$
so $$\alpha x^2 - \beta y^2 = C_2$$

Comment: Thank you for this. Does this show that it is independent of time?

Comment: The relation $\alpha x^2 - \beta y^2 = c$ holds at any time.